# how to change odoo server timezone to user timezone in attendance report

Tags: python, timezone, report, odoo

i have been customized an odoo report to print employee attendances the time of check in and out is correct in UI but when i print the report it increase 2 hours to every record

Comment: for the same user? can you put the code that you tried?

Comment: he only one user who used the system in kiosk mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a timezone problem: dates in Odoo are written as UTC datetime objects. When a date is rendered in the browser UI, it is automatically converted to the user's device timezone, but this conversion is not automatic when it comes to report, where datetime fields are rendered exactly as they are saved in the database.

Try to create a method that parses the datetime objects according to the user configuration:

```
import logging
import pytz
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def convert_datetime_field(datetime_field, user=None):
    dt = datetime.strptime(datetime_field, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if user and user.tz:
        user_tz = user.tz
        if user_tz in pytz.all_timezones:
            old_tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')
            new_tz = pytz.timezone(user_tz)
            dt = old_tz.localize(dt).astimezone(new_tz)
        else:
            _logger.info("Unknown timezone {}".format(user_tz))

    return datetime.strftime(dt, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score -2):

It was time zone problem. set up your correct time Zone.

Step 1.

**Click on your logged account name and choose preferences. **

Preferences
[image: Preferences]

Step 2

** change the time zone **
Time zone
[image: Time Zone]

Very simple.